# Error 500 after plugin installation attempt on Moodle

Tags: plugins, error-handling, moodle

I tried installing a plugin ([Upload Notification](https://moodle.org/plugins/local_uploadnotification)) but right before completing the installation I received the

> Error 500, the site is currently unable to handle this request.

I used the online version of Moodle, so I don't have physical access to the server. I can't even log in as admin, nor can guests.

Using Chrome's history, I initially managed to enter the plugins management page, I found the Upload Notification plugin and I tried to remove it, but with the same error (the site is currently unable to handle this request.). After that, I couldn't access any of the website pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've still got the value for the sesskey, then you could try this to uninstall the plugin - replacing xxxx with your sesskey

```
http://yoursite.com/admin/plugins.php?sesskey=xxxx&uninstall=local_uploadnotification&confirm=0&return=overview
```

---

Just had a look at the plugin, there is a comment about the 500 message saying it needs another plugin called changloglib

[image]

Which is a bit weird because its listed as a dependency in version.php

```
$plugin->component = 'local_uploadnotification';

// Require the backup and compare libs.
$plugin->dependencies = array(
    'local_changeloglib' => 2017123100,
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Russel, you've been already useful. You're right, I din't see the other plugin was required, so I didn't install that.
Following your suggestion, I tried recovering the url used for installing the Upload Notfication (http://www.thehubacademy.net/ehub/admin/tool/installaddon/index.php?installzipcomponent=local_uploadnotification&installzipstorage=07083803-4e62-4331-8ee1-f4bddc5d9e71&sesskey=FDw9IfFMwC) and I changed it to "http://www.thehubacademy.net/ehub/admin/plugins.php?sesskey=FDw9IfFMwC&uninstall=local_uploadnotification&confirm=0&return=overview", but the error is still there.

Comment: okay, try a bare minimum uninstall url - http://www.thehubacademy.net/ehub/admin/plugins.php?uninstall=local_uploadnotification or see if you can get to the plugins page and then click uninstall http://www.thehubacademy.net//admin/plugins.php

Comment: Thanks, we managed to find out who had the server files at hand and resolved this issue by removing the plugin's directory. Thanks again, since you've been the most helpful!